# How to simulate this circuit for common mode voltage effect?

Tags: ltspice, dac, common-mode

Regarding [my previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616733/confusion-with-using-non-inverting-input-to-fix-common-mode-voltage) and [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa344/sbaa344.pdf) paper, I wanted to simulate the circuit below to see whether it is rejecting common mode voltage as claimed. The paper says that sharing DAC's Vref with non-inverting node, the common mode voltage variation at Vref will not effect the output:

[image]

To try that, I first modeled the DAC and tried the following circuit in LTspice:

[image]

But I get the following plots for (Voutp - Voutn) and Vcm; showing that Vcm appears at the output:

[image]

Another similar variant of this circuit is as follows(with voltage divider):

[image]

And now I removed the ground of the DAC model and voltage divider to the non-inverting input as follows:

[image]

And now the output is quiet small:

[image]

I couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong. Or is my last try correct way to do this? How can this circuit be simulated in SPICE so that we can see the common mode error is eliminated as claimed?

Comment: Removing the ground will leave an open node, which works sometimes but sometimes introduces numerical instability. Technically there is a fp cap on those nodes but best to also put some resistance on it.

Comment: Does anything change if you use `[Opamps]->UniversalOpamp2` instead of the LM324?

Comment: The opamp you're using for the DAC is nothing but a G+(R||C).

Comment: @SteKulov No it didn't make any difference. Im looking for someone to simulate what that paper claims.

Comment: @ty_1917. I'd like to kindly make a suggestion: why not providing a quote, print or formula from the app. note, where it specifically claims that *"the common mode voltage variation at Vref will not effect the output:"*. It may help contributors to focus on that (proving or disproving, maybe).

Comment: @devnull That was what I understood from the paper. If you can describe why Vref is connected to one input I would be glad. And especially why to the non-inverting input. Since Im stuck I cannot get out of this and see where Im wrong. I appreciate any assistance which explain clearly and simple way what the paper is really claiming and a simulation would also show it very clearly.

Comment: In this paper here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/tech-articles/designing-dacs-into-precision-industrial-10-v-applications.pdf the buffered reference goes to the inverting input. U6-->U5-->U4. This is opposite to TI's paper.

Comment: This is an erroneous application of a common mode signal. Please describe the overall system you are simulating. From the description, it sounds like you have a voltage reference, DAC and differential transmitter system. 1. How would the reference be subject to common mode error? The reference is the most important signal in the circuit, why would it be exposed to a noise source? 2. There is one node only, Vref, not a difference; there is no common mode, this is normal mode, or single-ended; CM is meaningless here. 3. Would it not be more meaningful to simulate CM as a voltage offset...

Comment: ...added between transmitter (the circuit shown here) and a receiver (a completely separate circuit not shown here)?

Answer (score 0):

I simulated this using LT1007A for all three opamps, using the voltage divider. I got 237uV P-P with the dividers grounded and 470uV P-P without them grounded.

My output is also centered on 0 V.

[image]

I suspect the problem may be in the opamp model you're using for your DAC model.

Comment: You set R1 R2 and DAC resistors equal. But if you vary them you will see huge common mode voltage appear at the output. But in reality it shouldn't be the case. That should be independent of R1 and R2 and also DAC output. I doubt the models we tried is correct so far.

Comment: The whole point is to cancel out the common mode voltage by adding Vref in the inverting amplifier, if you change the voltage ratio of course you'll get high common mode voltage at the output. Without the second divider you get  1V + (-0.5V) = 0.5V, with it you get 0.5V + (-0.5V) = 0V.

Comment: Yes but that means the model is wrong. R2 can be a poti to change the range of the output. And imagine even R1 and R2 is equal when the DAC will vary(means in my DAC model its resistors will vary). That means this model would be useless unless it outputs zero always. I need a model that can replicate the real scenario.

Comment: When the DAC varies the common mode should not  vary that much. DAC model like mine can be wrong as well.

Comment: Shouldn't U3 source come from U1?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I don't know, I did it the way they show it in the TI paper. I think what's needed is an accurate model for the DAC, I just piggy-backed on what the OP came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Your model will only be correct at DC operating points and low frequency AC. You have frequency-dependent elements that won't be common-mode rejected that shows up as a differential-mode signal at the inputs as U2.

What I would do, is omit U1 (it does nothing useful from the standpoint of simulation) and change U3 to an ideal op-amp. This will correct your simulation results.

Another issue that you may be having is common-mode signals on a DAC reference input will be seen as a differential mode signal on following stages - it's effectively the "gain" of the DAC and output will scale accordingly.